# jquery locate position for new elements sorted

Tags: jquery, sorting

I've got the following elements on my page:

```
<div class="feedItem" data-moddate="1344738920" data-id="59920"></div>
<div class="feedItem" data-moddate="1344725719" data-id="59897"></div>
<div class="feedItem" data-moddate="1344722122" data-id="59876"></div>
<div class="feedItem" data-moddate="1344718218" data-id="59856"></div>
<div class="feedItem" data-moddate="1344716717" data-id="59854"></div>
```

When I dynamically insert a new item I would like to position it in the correct spot based on the 'moddate' data value.

It's important to get the position of where the element needs to go because I am planning on doing some animation when each new element arrives.

Any ideas?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502967/more-efficient-jquery-sort-method-for-dom-elements-based-on-numerical-attribute

Comment: You're just going to have to do a lot of sorting and checking back & forth with your current value where it's greater than one, and less than the other one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var i = 0;
var modDate = someTimestamp
$(".feedItem").each(function()
{
    if(modDate < $(this).data('moddate'))
    {
        return;
    }
    i++;
});
//The new element should be inserted AFTER $(".feedItem").eq(i);
```