# How i can change product display on a page with combox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using woocommerece with word press. I am getting image from data base by this query.

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'product',  'product_cat' => 'Rings', 'stock' => 1, 'posts_per_page' => 12, 'orderby' =>'$date','order' => 'DESC' );
```

then I use this code to display image on  page.

```
<div class="prodimg">
    <ul class="rcollpro">

    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product',  'product_cat' => 'Rings', 'stock' => 1, 'posts_per_page' => 12, 'orderby' =>'$date','order' => 'DESC' );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; ?>
        <li class="rcollproli"> 
          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $loop->post->ID )) echo get_the_post_thumbnail($loop->post->ID, 'shop_catalog'); else echo '<img src="'.woocommerce_placeholder_img_src().'" alt="Placeholder" width="65px" height="115px" />'; ?></a>

             <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
 <span class="price"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></span>
            <br />
            <?php woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart( $loop->post, $product ); ?></li>
        <!-- /span3 -->
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
    </ul>
    <!-- /row-fluid -->
</div>
```

I am using following code for combo box and java script

```
<select name="orderby" class="orderby" id="selector">
    <option value="menu_order">Default sorting</option>
    <option value="popularity">Sort by popularity</option>
    <option value="date">Sort by newness</option>
    <option value="price">Sort by price: low to high</option>
    <option value="price-desc">Sort by price: high to low</option>
</select>

$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#selector").change(function() {   
    var selectedValue = $("#selector option:selected").val();
    alert('Selected text ' + selectedValue);
  });
});
```

I want display  value (images from db) on page change accordingly, when user change value in combo box. DO I use ajax or I will find the solution with javascript?

Comment: If you have all the images on the page you need to show/hide the classes they belong to. Please format your code better next time

Comment: Thanks for advice. What i want to reorder displayed images on page as per combo selection. if user select by newest images on page will reorder in to date wise. If user select by price From low to high . image on page will display by price (asc). i want to know how to  achieve this.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502967/more-efficient-jquery-sort-method-for-dom-elements-based-on-numerical-attribute

Comment: i have look the question you mention, but my issue is different. I need to get code on how to manage display of image (not sorting without reloading whole page). when value on combobox change image on page change as accordingly

Comment: I do not follow. If your server adds all images to the page and you need to sort the dom objects according to price, date, popularity and price, then you need to add the criteria as date-attributes and sort on them. If not, you will need to request the images again and again from the server in the new order.

Comment: you have my code. If you help me how to write this in code. As i have no much experience of dom.

Comment: I have your php. Please post an example of generated html

Comment: these php  contain ul and li html tags. these are the html element structuring the page

Comment: If you want my help, produce some code I can play with. I do not have your data base and do not have time to create a test page.

Comment: i have given all code there.If you have no idea about this why you add so many comments on it?

Comment: I think you completely miss the point here.
I was willing to help you, but I was not willing to create an HTML test page based on your PHP. SO is not a site for "Gimme the codez" but some of us will help beyond what is expected here if we find the issue interesting. I am getting less and less interested since you do not provide me with a page I can apply my suggestion to and do not believe my suggestion is what you need.